# Compiling application to run not from the start of the flash stm32L4R9I

Tags: linker, usb, stm32, flash-memory, dfu

I have an steval-stwinkt1 board, that i am trying to enable support for DFU mode.

I flashed costume boot loader firmware on to the the start of the flash (0x8000000) that lets you load into another firmware that was uploaded by the DFU mode or to stay in the current program to flash new firmware throw the USB.

i used this st tutorial- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_LDXOQHerU

I tried the .dfu package that comes with the STM32Cube and i saw that the program ran successfully so i assume that the bootloader works.

but when i try to make my own DFU package from my software the software never loads and i get hard fault. i moved the software according to the ST totorial & some research i done to 0x800C000 by changin the following lines:

in the FLASH.ld file:

```c
    FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,   LENGTH = 2048K
```

to:

```c
    FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x800C000,   LENGTH = 2048K
```

and in the stm32l4r9xx.h changed FLASH_BASE to:

```c
    #define FLASH_BASE            (0x0800C000UL)
```

on another try i tried instead of changing `FLASH_BASE` to change `VECT_TAB_OFFSET` but it still didnt work.

to make the dfu package i use dfu-tool (i use linux) and use this command:

```bsh
    dfu-tool convert dfuse software.bin software.dfu
```

also tried to convert the hex int dfu package using the official tool that is used in the tutorial i used and still didnt work

what do i need to change to make my software works when i load the dfu package?

thanks

itay

Comment: still needs help, if some one have experienced with that

Comment: please need help

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you have overlooked the fact that your application-dedicated flash size is not going to be 2048K anymore, since your custom bootloader is now placed at the start of the flash. Therefore, you need to subtract the app's flash origin from the total flash size:

```
 FLASH    (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x800C000,    LENGTH = 2048K - (ORIGIN(FLASH) - 0x8000000)
```

In such cases, a suggestion would be to try to debug the hard fault using the `HardFault_Handler()` and a bit of coding. You will then be able to extract and analyze the link register, program counter, program status register, etc. at the moment when hard fault occurred.

Comment: based on the openocd programmer output when i get the Hard fault the registers are:
xPSR: 0x00000003 pc: 00000000 msp: 0x464c4560
changing the liker to what you wrote didnt repair

Comment: @Finci - I guess I also miscalculated the flash length. I just edited the answer. Try to see if that works for you. Have in mind that you still need to have the `VECT_TAB_OFFSET ` defined as the current address of the interrupt vector table.

Comment: i have VECT_TAB_OFFSET set to 0xC000 and the FLASH line set to the exact line in the comment, and now i dont get HardFault from the programmer, but the program still does not load

Comment: after some more testing (without changing any thing)  I still get5 hard fault every time, it looks like the board still try to start from  0 instead of the right location
it dosent matter if i try to run using the DFU boot loader or just trying to program directly- both ways lead to dead program